# tidyr: more elegant way to pivot data frame

Tags: r, tidyr, transformation

I've got the following data frame:

| country | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ethiopia | 35 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Lithuania | 41 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Fiji | 50 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| Haiti | 33 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| France | 40 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| UAE | 41 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Sint Maarten | 44 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Denmark | 39 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| UK | 52 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| US | 39 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I would like to pivot it to the following format:

| variables | Ethiopia | Lithuania | Fiji | Haiti | France | UAE | Sint Maarten | Denmark | UK | US |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 35 | 41 | 50 | 33 | 40 | 41 | 44 | 39 | 52 | 39 |
| v2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| v3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| v4 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 |

I came up with the following solution that works but seems overly complicated:

```
new_df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -country,
               names_to = "type",
               values_to = "value") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = type,
              names_from = country,
              values_from = value)
```

**QUESTION:** Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

MWE:

```
set.seed(2)

df <- data.frame(country = c("Ethiopia", 
                             "Lithuania", 
                             "Fiji", 
                             "Haiti", 
                             "France", 
                             "UAE", 
                             "Sint Maarten", 
                             "Denmark", 
                             "UK", 
                             "US"),   
                 v1 = round(rnorm(10, 40, 6),0),
                 v2 = sample(c(1:2),5,replace = T),
                 v3 = sample(c(1:2),5,replace = T),
                 v4 = sample(c(1:3),5,replace = T))
```

Comment: Nothing's really changed since the duplicate. `tidyr` doesn't have a single function for transposing a tibble. But `data.table` does: `data.table::transpose(df, keep.names="variables", make.names="country")`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MrFlick and for marking the question as a duplicate! I should have been more precise with my phrasing as I realize now that my question implies a solution with `tidyr` when I was actually looking for any alternative way of doing this in one line regardless of the technique/package used. I missed the question that is linked above when I was looking for a solution and before posting here, but your `data.table` solution is exactly what I was looking for!